# not getting bootstrap brokers using the AWS CLI .i am using AWS IAM authentication method for the cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, amazon-iam, connection-string, aws-msk

I cannot list my bootstrap brokers using the AWS CLI from my ec2. but I am able to get all other information like, describe, zookeeper connection string, and list clusters using aws cli. Have I missed any permission for my MSK cluster?
when i hit the command `"aws kafka get-bootstrap-brokers --cluster-arn arn:aws:kafka:ap-souxxeaxxxxxxxcluster/ashixxxxx-88xxxxxxx68ce9b87-3"`, i get a blank output.